# Google Analytics Data API v1 Error 403 with access token (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, google-analytics-api

I am trying to access data from my users' Google Analytics 4 accounts using oauth authentication, with their access token. So far I have been accessing their Universal Analytics data and have had no problems.

But with the new API, using the url:

[https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/${propertyId}:runReport](https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/$%7BpropertyId%7D:runReport)

It returns:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this property. To learn more about Property ID, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/property-id.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I have tried it with my analytics account, with which I am the owner and administrator of all my properties and it also gives me the same error.

The code I am using within my NodeJS server is the following:

```js
static async runReport (config: any) {
      const { userId, propertyId } = config;
      const token = await getUserGoogleAnalyticsAccessToken(userId);

      const response = await fetch(
          `https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/${propertyId}:runReport`,
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          dimensions: [
            {
              name: 'country',
            },
          ],
          metrics: [
            {
              name: 'activeUsers',
            },
            {
              name: 'totalEvents',
            },
          ],
          dateRanges: [
            {
              startDate: '2023-01-01',
              endDate: '2023-01-31',
            },
          ],
        }),
      });

    console.log(response)

    if (response.status === 403) {
      console.log("Forbidden. Check your permissions and token.");
    }
```

I have verified that the token is updated since I can access the Google Analytics Reporting v4 API without problem. Does anyone know how to solve it?

- The userId and propertyId variables are arriving correctly as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it with postman?

Comment: Yes, following this info: 

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport?hl=es-419

I have tried to post to this url:

https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/XXXXXXXXXX:runReport

with the access token active and I receive this response:

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this property. To learn more about Property ID, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/property-id.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Comment: Just a guess: maybe you need other credentials for the beta access then for the released one?